# How to get the running path of a Symfony Console application?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

Is there any way to get the running path in a [Symfony Console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/index.html) application? For example (assuming php interpreter in `PATH`):

```
cd /tmp
php /home/user/myapplication/app/console.php mycommand
```

Should return `/tmp` as `console.php` was launched from `/tmp`.

Comment: Maybe use `getcwd()`?

Comment: @mkjasinski what happens if i run the command with `exec` from Symfony controller (web environment)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`getcwd()` will do what you need. You can execute app/console from any directory, and PHP will know which one it is.

I used the following example to verify this.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class DemoCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('demo:cwd')
            ->setDescription('Get Current Working Directory')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln(getcwd());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this work when command is executed from a controller (i.e. web page)?

Comment: Just did a test with the Symfony Process in a controller action and it certainly does work. Do you plan to execute your command using `Symfony\Component\Process\Process` ?

Comment: Yes, maybe executing and capturing the output, but for the first time it will run as a simple console application. Really thank you for helping!